# Is it possible to create a public-URL (accessible from anywhere) for an image stored in the iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, image-gallery

I am trying to create an iOS APP where whole media gallery of the user needs to be imported to my server but I don't want to consume user's network data to PUSH the media on to my server. The motive is to PULL the image / media at the Server from the iOS client .

So was wondering if somehow we could create the public URL (making the iOS device work as server for a while) of the media and PULL the media using it at my server.

If this sounds impractical then can anyone suggest a better way to import whole gallery of the user (provided user has given its consent for the same).

Comment: If you expose the phone as server the 1st problem you will have to manage is how can the customer phones stays online for your server, the next problem is security how can you make sure your server and only your sever tries to connect to your customer's phone.  I am pretty sure as device user I won't like the idea that my phone is expose publicly on internet. 
I would suggest to make your app  detect when the apple device is connected to WiFi then only then start the transfer and you need to make sure you let the user know what is happen, or you can ask user if wants to use his data.

Comment: @JuValencia : Correct me if I am wrong , in case of public URL , won't it be my server's data when I am pulling / downloading it ?

Comment: if the data that you are pulling to your server is in your's user phone, technically belongs to him. My point to make is you can push the data while the phone is connected to a WiFi, or for example there are companies in which data is not a problem (for example my data plan is 75GB) so I would have no issues to use my data to upload 10GB of it.

Comment: @JuValencia , Yes the security concern is there in my approach . And your suggestion of making the app to detect "Wifi.." sounds great . Surely I will try your approach . But I am still curious to know if it is at all possible to let my approach work ( I mean , can we create a public URL of an image residing in an iOS device) . Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Well technically is possible (in theory), but then your server (phone's app) will have to subscribe to some sort of domain updater so your server gets its current IP, because phones changes ip frequently and this is manage by the carrier.  The next problem is how to make sure the Carrier is not blocking the port that your server (the server that pulls the data) is using, and the user can't request the carrier to open those ports. That is why I am suggesting that approach, because you can control that your server always has the same ip/domain name.

Comment: Whether the data is sent from the phone or "pulled" by the server, the same amount of data will be transmitted from the user's phone and they  will consume the same amount of data from their data plan.

Comment: @JuValencia , Thanks buddy for your replies . I appreciate it.

Comment: @Paulw11 , if that is the case then it's a news to me . I will surely read more to understand it . Possible for you to point me to any relevant article for the same ? Thanks.

Comment: It is just how networks work.  It doesn't matter how a transfer is initiated, a certain number of bytes need to be transmitted from the phone to the server.  If your phone data plan counts uploads as well as downloads (They do in my country (Australia)) then the transfer will come off the data plan regardless of how the transfer was initiated.

Comment: @Paulw11 , one more question related to this . Like FB API provides you the public url for the media posted . So if I initiate (PULL) download of the same at my server , what will be the cost in terms of network ? My understanding is that , I will be spending my network (i.e my server will consume my network) to download this file . And it will cost NOTHING to the FB .

Comment: It might cost Facebook something, it might not. It depends on the agreement they have with their internet provider, but the way that data is metered on high speed data center networks for massive companies is very different to how data is metered for a single mobile device with a mobile data connection. Think of it this way; if you go to the post office and send a package they want you to pay for it regardless of whether you just decided to send it or if your brother asked you to send it. You need to check your mobile plan but almost certainly data you send will be metered

Comment: it doesn't matter whether the data was "pushed" or "pulled". That is completely invisible to the telco's metering and billing system. It just sees data sent and received.

Comment: @Paulw11 , thanks for your explanation .